# postgres join list with $ delimiter

Tags: string, postgresql, join, delimiter

From these tables:

```
select group, ids 
from some.groups_and_ids;
```

Result:

```
group   | group_ids
     ---+----  
winners | 1$4
losers  | 4  
others  | 2$3$4
```

and:

```
select id,name from some.ids_and_names; 

id | name  
---+----  
1  | bob  
2  | robert
3  | dingus
4  | norbert
```

How would you go about returning something like:

```
winners | bob, norbert
losers  | norbert 
others  | robert, dingus, norbert
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing delimited values in a single column in the first place. It would be better if you normalize your datamodel.

Answer (score 3):

```
with normalized  (group_name, id) as (
  select group_name, unnest(string_to_array(group_ids,'$')::int[])
  from groups_and_ids
)
select n.group_name, string_agg(p.name,',' order by p.name)
from normalized n
  join ids_and_names p on p.id = n.id
group by n.group_name;
```

The first part (the [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)) normalizes your broken table design by creating a proper view on the `groups_and_ids` table. The actual query then joins the `ids_and_names` table to the normalized version of your groups and the aggregates the names again.

Note I renamed `group` to `group_name` because  `group` is a reserved keyword.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2205b/2

Comment: This answer is cleaner than mine - using "with" makes the query more understandable and casting the array inside the "with" makes everything that little bit clearer. It also makes the deficiencies in the table design obvious!

Comment: How would you sort the names that are returned? :)

Comment: I mean the names within the string

Comment: @user3486527: that's in my edit: `string_agg(p.name,',' order by p.name)`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to redesign your database? Putting all the group_ids into one column makes life hard. If your table was e.g.

```
group | group_id

winners | 1
winners | 4
losers | 4
```

etc. this would be trivially easy. As it is, the below query would do it, although I hesitated to post it, since it encourages bad database design (IMHO)!

p.s. I took the liberty of renaming some columns, because they are reserved words. You can escape them, but why make life difficult for yourself?

```
select group_name,array_to_string(array_agg(username),', ') -- array aggregation and make it into a string
from

(
select group_name,theids,username
from ids_and_names
inner join

(select group_name,unnest(string_to_array(group_ids,'$')) as theids -- unnest a string_to_array to get rows

from groups_and_ids) i
on i.theids = cast(id as text)) a
group by group_name
```